# How to turn off autocomplete while keep using datalist element in html

Tags: html, autocomplete, browser-history, html-datalist

I have a `input` field which shows a list using html5 `<datalist>` element. The problem is that with `<datalist>` the browser autocomplete also shows the history list (which is the list of previously typed values, that are not included in the `<datalist>`). So I just want to get rid of the `history-list` not the `<datalist>`.

If I use the `autocomplete = "off"` feature, this also blocks the `<datalist>`.

In short, I just want the `<datalist>` not the history one.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Seems like an oversight not to include a way to disambiguate between these two.

Comment: I didn't meet the issue of blocking `datalist`. Checked under Firefox 63.0.3 and Chromium 70.0.3538.110. Everything works as expected with `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 23):

Is it possible for you to use the `input` field without an `id` or `name` attribute?  Without that, the browser doesn't really have any way to associate a history with that element.

In my *real quick* testing on Firefox, this seemed to do the trick:

```
<form>
  <!-- these will remember input -->
  With id: <input id="myInputId" list="myList" /><br />
  With name: <input name="myInputName" list="myList" /><br />

  <!-- these will NOT remember input -->
  No id, name, class: <input list="myList" /><br />
  With class: <input class="myInputClass" list="myList" />

  <datalist id="myList">
    <option value="Option 1"></option>
    <option value="Option 2"></option>
  </datalist>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the code above, the `input`s with an `id` or `name` would remember past values, but the `input` without anything and the input with just a `class` would **not** remember anything.

Unfortunately, this does make using the `input` slightly more difficult if you *need* it to have a `name` or `id`.  In that case, I'd try having an `id`'ed `input` which is also `display: none`'ed and then use some JavaScript to keep it in sync with an `input` that won't remember past values.

Comment: Ah, good suggestion. In fact, I just realized I actually solved the same problem on my own question by using an `<input type="hidden">` and leaving out the name on the real input. I keep them in sync with a simple piece of jquery:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756791/html-datalist-with-fallback-causes-duplicate-query-string-parameters

Comment: @StephanMuller yup, that's exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: Interesting suggestion, can someone confirm if the same works for Chrome as well? I presume even chrome remembers history based on ID?

Comment: Tested in Chrome and it works as advertised. However, my HTML is generated from JSP and I can't avoid using "name" attribute since it is needed for mapping. Any other solutions?

Comment: In the latest versions of Firefox (50) and Chrome (55), using `autocomplete="off"` on the `input` has the expected behavior: it disables the history but shows the `datalist` options.

Answer (score 15):

Try using the HTML attribute autocomplete

```
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

source [Turn Off Autocomplete for Input](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/)

Comment: Thanks! That'll teach me to read the docs first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: The op did say that they used `autocomplete` attribute.

Comment: The issue arise in combination with datalist... After you've submited the form, it remembers datalist value previously selected, though autocomplete is "off". I just faced it now under firefox 62.0.3

Comment: I found that in Chrome, it was still suggesting wrong things at the bottom depending on the name of the input and/or datalist. Ex. field name medNames showed a few of my name combinations at the bottom. By using the datalist id for the autocomplete value prevented that.

Comment: Easiest and best solution. I did not face the problem that OP did; connect input with `list = "datlistID"`. (I also use placeholder for old value)

Answer (score 3):

I use a code like this:

```
<input name="anrede" list="anrede" onmousedown="value = '';" />
<datalist id="anrede">
    <option value="Herr"></option>
    <option value="Frau"></option>
</datalist>
```

**good**: The datalist shown for selection is complete

**bad** : The input field is empty, 
      therefore the old value is not documented, 
      if needed to be remembered by the user

Comment: If you want to remember the input value for the user, put the value also in the placeholder="value" - so it's a little help for the user ;-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use autocomplete="new-password". autocomplete = "off" didn't worked in my case.

```
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="new-password"/>
```

Comment: This was the best answer as it only shows the actual datalist options AND that which has been typed in that before. But, I was using the name/id of the datalist for the autocomplete value. Not sure where new password came from

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it works.

```
<input id="datalisttestinput" list="stuff" autocomplete="off"></input>
<datalist id="stuff">
     <option id="1" value="Amy">
     <option id="2" value="Kristal">
     <option id="3" value="Collin">
     <option id="4" value="Carl">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<datalist id="datalist_id">
```

js:

```
dataList = $("#datalist_id")
dataList.empty()
```

This will clear the datalist's history. This worked for me on chrome.
Then if you want to add options to the list, try:

```
dataList.append("<option>Some Option</option>")
```

Cheers !!!